# can I use breakpoints with try catch statements with qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, try-catch

if an exception is thrown inside a try/catch, can i put a breakpoint there to get into debu mode before the program exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested here with a simple code, were I called a function that always throw. The breakpoints inside de catch block not ignored, and the debug mode started normally.

Anyway, qtCreator uses GDB for debugging (At least on my machine). You can find out more about how GDB handle exceptions debugging here http://www.caf.dk/cafonly/gnu/gdb/gdb_31.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not, this can certainly be done with the C/C++ IDE in Eclipse just by clicking in the margin where you want to break and running in "debug mode". In Eclipse, there is a run and a run in debug mode separation - I assume that's the case also in Qt Creator. Try it?

Comment: well I know I can place  a break point in debug  mode anywhere in the program but was wondering if these breakpoints where ignorede when an exception is thrown.